# Cannot see a public method defined inside a fragment

Tags: android

I have defined a public method inside a fragment to set the value of an internal variable. But I cannot access (cannot see) the method outside the fragment (e.g. from Main activity class). I'm probably missing something but cannot figure it out. Every help is appreciated.

My fragment code is below (I removed import packages for brevity):

```
package com.example.lenovo.apptel_book;


public class my_add_fragment extends Fragment {

int temp_data;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_add_fragment, container, false);
}

public void set_data(int x)
{
    temp_data = x;
}

}
```

I want to access the "set_data" method when a given button is clicked. Within the onClick method, i use the code below:

```
public void main_Add_Click(View v)
{
    Fragment fr = new my_add_fragment();

    // need to access fr.set_data() but cannot see the method!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
my_add_fragment fr = new my_add_fragment();
```

Instead of this

```
Fragment fr = new my_add_fragment();
```